# Affine group, $[L : \mathbb{Q}] = n\varphi(n)$ or ${1\over2}n\varphi(n)$

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $L$ be the Galois closure of $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{a})$, where $a \in \mathbb{Q}$, $a > 0$ and suppose $[K : \mathbb{Q}] = n$. How do I see that $[L: \mathbb{Q}] = n\varphi(n)$ or ${1\over2}n\varphi(n)$?

**Remarks.**

- Note that $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n) \cap K$ is a Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.
- Is there a way to use the affine group here?

Comment: Have you looked in Lang's Algebra? He has a discussion of this in a section titled "The equation $X^n-a$."